# Ошибка Nginx при работе с ElasticSearch

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, elasticsearch

При работе с ElasticSearch появляется ошибка:

```
2015/11/13 09:50:20 [error] 1961#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection       refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: arena.local,    request: "GET /resume/search.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9100",   host: "arena.local"
```

На странице браузура отображается:

```
Missing404Exception in GuzzleConnection.php line 271:
{"error":"IndexMissingException[[arena] missing]","status":404}
```

А так же:

```
Client error response
[status code] 404
[reason phrase] Not Found
[url] http://127.0.0.1:9200/arena/resume/_search?size=10
```

Не могу разобраться так как еще плохо втыкаю в теме, помогите.

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я понимаю *elasticsearch* говорит о том, что у тебя нет индекса *arena* к которому обращается код. Проверьте, индекс вообще существует?

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/_stats
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/arena/_stats
```

[Indices Stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html)